# What do you put in RegistrySpec.xml for Izpack installation to set Size field

Tags: izpack

## This is my xml file for installer.

```
    <izpack:registry version="5.0"
                     xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/registry"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/registry http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-registry-5.0.xsd">

        <pack name="UninstallStuff">
            <!-- Special "pack", if not defined an uninstall key will be generated automatically -->
            <!-- The variable $UNINSTALL_NAME can be only used if CheckedHelloPanel will be used
                   because there the variable will be declared. With that variabel it is possible
                   to install more as one instances of the product on one machine each with an
                   unique uninstall key. -->
            <value name="DisplayName"
                keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$APP_NAME $APP_VER"
                root="HKLM"
                string="$APP_NAME" />
            <value name="DisplayVersion"
                keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$APP_NAME $APP_VER"
                root="HKLM"
                string="$APP_VER" />
            <value name="UninstallString"
                keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$APP_NAME $APP_VER"
                root="HKLM"
                string="&quot;$JAVA_HOME\bin\javaw.exe&quot; -jar &quot;$INSTALL_PATH\uninstaller\uninstaller.jar&quot;" />
            <value name="DisplayIcon"
                keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$APP_NAME $APP_VER"
                root="HKLM"
                string="$INSTALL_PATH\icon\uninstallericon.ico" />
            <value name="Publisher"
                keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$APP_NAME $APP_VER"
                root="HKLM"
                string="opname" />
        </pack>
    </izpack:registry>
```

I am getting publisher name but i am not able to get size field value.How can i add size field in add remove program.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've probably found the solution by now (or given up) as this question is over three years old, but I have found the solution. It doesn't seem to be documented on the IzPack site, but digging through the schema and the registry settings of other installed programs reveals the answer.

Application size is stored in the registry as a 32-bit DWORD value, which is the application's size in KB, under the key "EstimatedSize". For example, for a 100MB (==102400KB) application, your configuration would look like the following:

```
<value name="EstimatedSize"
       keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$APP_NAME $APP_VER"
       root="HKLM"
       dword="102400" />
```